# Kendo DatePicker Return wrong value

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-datepicker

I set the format of my date in this way:

```
$('#filterdate').kendoDatePicker({format: "dd/MM/yyyy"});
```

SOMEWHERE I have code which set (#filterdate)

**#filterdate** is *10/7/2014*

but when I use this code :

```
$('#filterdate').data("KendoDatePicker").value();
```

it returns : *10 Jun 2014*

why the dates are different?
its really strange. I think I have problem in initializing Kendo (maybe) .

Comment: Try `$("#filterdate").kendoDatePicker({parseFormats:["dd/MM/yyyy"]});`

Comment: I fill **filterdate** with a simple function returns a string of date: exactly it returns :_10/7/2014_

Comment: @Thanasis : its doesnt work with that, still Error in converting .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First important question about dates is that months (as @LarsHöppner) already noted are base 0.
- Second, depending on your language/country settings -if you are using others than defaults- you might need to use both `parseFormats` (used when you set a date) and `format` (used for displaying the date in the input box).
- Third, there is a typo error in `$('#filterdate').data("KendoDatePicker").value();` where `KendoDatePicker` is with lowercase `K`, but since you say that it shows a date instead of complaining by an undefined, it is fine.

Said so, if you initialize the DatePicker as:

```
var fd = $("#filterdate").kendoDatePicker({
    parseFormats:["dd/MM/yyyy"],
    format: "dd/MM/yyyy"
}).data("kendoDatePicker");
```

it works perfectly fine, both setting and getting a date as:

Setting:

```
fd.value("10/7/2014");
```

and Getting:

```
var value = fd.value();
```

Check it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5q1tnh1j/

Comment: How Can I thank You. YES. It works! just for formatting when I want to get data. so many thanks :)